# Azure Pipelines How and where to change the agent specification

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am new to this.

When I run the deployment I get this error.

Job issues
1 error
1 warning
An image label with the label Ubuntu16 does not exist.

Under Agent Pools, Microsoft hosted agent job is showing Ubunt-16.04. How and where do I go change the value for this.

[Azure Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMvRr.png)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are using the classic or yaml pipeline version, but when you are creating the job, you can specify which agent you need.

In the classic version you must choose the correct pool and after that you can indicate the version of ubuntu that you need. I prefer to use the ubuntu latest always

Classic pipeline example:
[image: classic pipeline example]

In the yaml version you just must pass this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
```